# Complex Relationship Mapping using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have this database

```
Packages (packageID, package_name , .... )
PackageVariant (packageID, variantID)
Variant (variantID, variant_name, .... )
VariantProduct (variantID, productID, quantity)
Product (productID, product_name, .... )
```

I have modelled it in Entity Framework, I don't know the multiplicities but they should be based on below:

A Package can have None or Multiple Variants
A Variant can be associated with only One Package (can't be none or multiple)
One Variant can have One or Multiple Products
Products are associated with None or Multiple Variants

When a Package is deleted, all Variants of that Package must be deleted.
When a Variant is deleted nothing else is needed to be deleted.
When a Product is deleted, all associations with Variants need to be deleted.

If you can provide help with the multiplicities and where the OnDelete:Cascade needs to be set that would be great!

I also need to be able to do this:

```
var ptx = new MyEntities();
Variant newVariant = new Variant()
{
    setRelevantProperty = value
};
Product selectedProduct = ptx.Products.First(o => o.productID == productID);
newVariant.Products.Add(selectedProduct);
Package packageToAddVariantTo = ptx.Packages.First(o => o.packageID == packageID);
packageToAddVariantTo.Variants.Add(newVariant);
ptx.SaveChanges();
```

without getting an error due to "There is no Insert, Update set" or anything else that relies on the mappings. So how to correctly map this complex database would be good :)

I have read a few posts, books and I can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks

Comment: this is what I'm getting error wise at the moment "Unable to update the EntitySet 'PackageVariant' because it has a DefiningQuery and no element exists in the element to support the current operation."

Comment: Did you run "Update model from database" in the EDMX designer (because you "have a database")? And what "have you modelled" then? Or are you using Code-First? Or Model-First?

Comment: Is packagevariant a view or a table ?

Comment: PackageVariant as describe above is a table. I don't understand what you're saying Slauma, I created a database, then used Entity Model to model the concept of the database.

Comment: It's been said that I need to create a composite primary key on the PackageVariant and VariantProduct tables

Comment: @No1_Melman: I don't understand what you are saying either. When you add an Entity Model to your project you get the offer to either start with an empty model or to create a model from an existing database. What option did you choose? If you have already created the DB you should have chosen the second option. But it sounds like you have chosen the first option (start with empty model). Why? This is duplicate work...

Comment: Well when I say "I have modelled it in Entity Framework" I think you can safely assume that I clicked Add New Item, Entity Framework, From Database! Seeing as I put at the top "I have this database" meaning I have a database that has been created to those specs as listed.

Comment: OK, but why do you need to create or edit the mapping then? Using "From database" means that the model and all relationships including the correct multiplicities should have been already created. Or does your database only have tables/columns but no foreign key constraints (=relationships) between tables?

Comment: I've put in all foreign keys, primary keys and made composite keys for the joining tables. This has been done through the database designer, now it all works. The only thing I need to do is add a constraint that means when a package is delete, it cascades down through associated variants, but not through the products!

Comment: Yes the issue is that if a table has no primary key defined it is effectively treated as a view by EF. That is why you had the defining query.

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer to your question but I would make 1 recommendation, get rid of the PackageVariant table. You only need a table like that when you have a multiple to multiple relationship. Just add a column in the variant table called packageId and make it a foreign key to the package table and not null. This will enforce your rule of 1 package exactly per variant. But none to multiple variants per package.

Comment: That is genius Lee O, thanks will implement that as soon as!! I was wondering for ages why there was a joining table, just getting carried away with the complexity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lee O got the answer, I'll just re post it as an answer rather than a comment for reader clarity:

I'm not sure of the answer to your question but I would make 1 recommendation, get rid of the PackageVariant table. You only need a table like that when you have a multiple to multiple relationship. Just add a column in the variant table called packageId and make it a foreign key to the package table and not null. This will enforce your rule of 1 package exactly per variant. But none to multiple variants per package.

Thanks Lee